# Excel VBA: Beta retrieve function not working in my sub

Tags: excel, vba

I've modified an existing piece of code in order to retrieve Beta values of french stocks from reuters.com. The function seems to be working when I use it within a spreadsheet (e.g. =getbeta(A3) with EDF.PA in cell A3.

```
'Beta Function. Posted by mybeam on http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/780746-excel-how-pull-beta-stock-yahoo-finance.html
Function GetBeta(ByVal trange As Range) As Single

  Dim xHttp As Object
  Dim t, Ticker  As String

  Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

  Ticker = trange.Text

  xHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=" & Ticker, False
  xHttp.Send
  t = xHttp.responseText

  t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">Beta:<") + 1)
  t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">") + 1)
  t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">") + 1)
  t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">") + 1)

  GetBeta = Val(Left(t, InStr(t, "<") - 1))

End Function
```

However, I would now like to use the function as part of a sub. Unfortunately the code below is not working. It seems that that I'm having issues with the variables/objects.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
  Dim Beta As Double
  Dim Ticker_A As Range

  Select Case Userform1.ComboBox_D.Value
  Case "ACCOR"
    Ticker_A = "AC.PA"
  Case "ELECTRICITE DE FRANCE"
    Ticker_A = "EDF.PA"

  Beta = GetBeta(Range(Ticker_A))

  MsgBox Beta

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: hey captain, thank you for having a look at this. I get a runtime error 91 Object variable or with  block variable not set

Comment: where is your code placed? is `Userform1` initialized when you execute your sub?

Comment: the function is placed in a module. The CommandButton4 is part of userform1 and the whole sub will be started when clicking the button. I therefore think that userform1 is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have mad few changes. Instead of range you might want to set it as string and also put end select

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

   Dim Beta As Double
   Dim Ticker_A As String

   Select Case UserForm1.ComboBox_D.Value
   Case "ACCOR"
       Ticker_A = "AC.PA"
   Case "ELECTRICITE DE FRANCE"
       Ticker_A = "EDF.PA"
   End Select

   Beta = GetBeta(Ticker_A)
   MsgBox Beta

End Sub


Public Function GetBeta(trange As String) As Single

    Dim xHttp As Object
    Dim t, Ticker  As String

    Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    Ticker = trange

    xHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=" & Ticker, False
    xHttp.Send
    t = xHttp.responseText

    t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">Beta:<") + 1)
    t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">") + 1)
    t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">") + 1)
    t = Mid(t, InStr(t, ">") + 1)

    GetBeta = Val(Left(t, InStr(t, "<") - 1))

End Function
```

Comment: well spotted the missing `End Select` ... +1

Answer (score 0):

I recon you have a problem with variable types. In your initial case `trange` is clearly a range. After conversion to a Sub you load a text into `Ticker_A` which you use as a range address in your call of the  `GetBeta` function.

This would work as long as there are named ranges "AC.PA" and "EDF.PA" in your sheet which I doubt. So you may need to change the parameter type of your `GetBeta` function to a string and just this instead of local variable `Ticker`